# GCM not unregistered after uninstalling app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have problem with automatic unregistration after uninstalling app. I have been waiting about 20 hours but the result never returns NotRegistered. I read all topics about GCM from documentation. Is there something what I missed?

**EDIT**

When I am trying to unregistered by code it isn't work and messages still comming. There is the code which I am using for unregistering.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     gcm =GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

     unregisterInBackground();   
}

private void unregisterInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            String msg = "";
            try {

               gcm.unregister();

                msg = "Device was succesfully unregistered";


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

            }
            return msg;
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
}
```

Comment: did you unregister() by code ?

Comment: Did you send messages to the device after the app was uninstalled?

Comment: Yes I tried it by code but it not works for me. Messages still comming.

Comment: I sent many messages after uninstalling. It always returns messageId.

Comment: please, show some code, where you send unregister()